# Deleting an element from a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists `A` and `B`. I want to delete the element in `A` from `B`. I present the current and expected output.

```
B=[4,5,1]
A=[1]
del B[A[0]]
print(B)
```

The current output is

```
[4,1]
```

The expected output is

```
[4,5]
```

Comment: Have you checked `list.remove`?

Comment: What you’re doing deletes by index, not by value.

Comment: Effectively `del B[1]` and you are surprised the element at index 1 is removed!?

Comment: Try to run this type of small program in the visual platform next time - https://pythontutor.com/  to learn step-by-step ops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention the code, the code will delete an item with index `A[0]` which is `1`. So you can visualize this `del B[A[0]]` = `del B[1]` = delete an element which has index 1 in B

Your final code should be:

You can `set` to do this

```
B=[4,5,1]
A=[1]

C = set(B) - set(A)

print(list(C))
```

in this code we are turning list to set and after subtract we will turn the result into list again

or use for loop

```
 B=[4,5,1]
    A=[1]
    for item in A:
        B.remove(item)
    
    print(B)
```

here, you can use for loop, it will loop for every item in A and will remove it from B